# passing variables to another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm getting "client is not defined". I can see client is not defined for the function but I'm not sure how to pass in client into the async. I don't think I'm actually returning the value of the each correct to pg_commit either or am I?

Basically I want to have an array of queries and loop over them and make them queries and then when all done commit those as a transaction.

```
var pg_conn_str = "postgres://postgres:5432@localhost/test2";

var pg = require ('pg');

var rollback = function (client, done) {
    client.query ('ROLLBACK', function (err) {
            return done (err);
    });
};

var queries = ["INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (4)",
               "INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (5)"];

pg.connect (pg_conn_str, function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) throw err;
        client.query ('BEGIN', function (err) {
                if (err) return rollback (client, done);
                process.nextTick (function() {
                        if (err)
                console.log (err);

            async.each (queries, pg_commit, function () {
                                client.query ('COMMIT', done);
                console.log ('done');
                            });



                    }); //nextTick                                              
            }); //begin                                                         
    }); //connect                                                               

function pg_commit (val) {
    client.query (val, function (err) {
            if (err) return rollback (client, done);
        });
    return (val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `client` variable is *defined* only within the callback function called by `pg.connect` method (as its param). But in `pg_commit` this name is meaningless - as this function is not defined within the scope of the callback function and doesn't have access to its name bindings.

Hence you have two solutions: either move `pg_commit` definition into the callback...

```
function (err, client, done) {
     if (err) throw err;
     var pg_commit = function(val) { client.query(val, function(err) { ... }};
     // ...
```

... or leave it where it is now, but change it into a function generator:

```
function pg_commit_generator(client) {
  return function(val) { client.query(val, function(){}); /*...*/ }
}
```

... then use this generator to create a function called by `async.each`:

```
async.each(queries, pg_commit_generator(client), function() {...});
```

Alternatively, you can just supply into `async.each` the anonymous function that calls `pg_commit`:

```
async.each(queries, function(val) { return pg_commit(val, client); }, ...);
```

... and adjust `pg_commit` accordingly (so it'll take `client` as a second param).

Comment: O.K. so I treid the anonymous function that calls pg_commit. That seems to print out what I want but how do I have a callback to know that all the of async.each have completed?

Comment: From [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) doc: `[third argument] - a callback which is called after all the iterator functions have finished, or an error has occurred`.